# Exit Code of command is 0, but binaries exit code is 3

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

How can parse the exit code from a command `snyk` where an exit code is `3` but `$?`'s value is `0`

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bin test -d --json --all-projects | tee >> file.json

ret=$?
echo "ret was $ret"

if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
echo "No vulns"

elif [ $ret -eq 1 ]; then
echo "got vulns"

elif [ $ret -eq 2 ]; then
echo "not all dependencies"

elif [ $ret -eq 3 ]; then
echo "dont have all req manifest"

else
echo "I got nothing"

fi
```

This is outputting:

```
ret was 0
No vulns
```

How can I parse this `Snyk Exit code: 3` and modify my final `elif` block instead to hit the final `elif [ $ret -eq 3 ]; then` block?

Thanks

Comment: This is the exit status of `tee`.

Comment: Wow, that was so simple, but so dumb on my part . Thanks @KamilCuk